# Format text in post_tweet command in rtweet package

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am using the post_tweet functionality of the `rtweet` package in R.

It correctly has a 280 character limit, and will not post the tweet if the message length exceeds that.

However, I want to add some formatting to the tweet and the formatting items seem to be counted in the character limit.  This is fine if the total number of characters is less than 280, but otherwise it won't post the tweet.

For example, if the text to post is

> UK stats as of 19 Nov 2020 15:32 \n Cases rep'd on 19 Nov 2020=22915 \n Tests on 18 Nov 2020=367626 \n Deaths rep'd on 19 Nov 2020=501 \n Cases per 100k in w/e  14 Nov 2020 :  Eng:273.4 (up 7.97%)  NI:210.3 (down 0.3%)  Scot':144.2 (down 6.46%)  Wales:180.5 (down 20.43%)  UK:256.6 (up 5.76%)

Then the number of characters is 290 and the command with this as the text in this:

```
post_tweet(<<<the text>>>)
```

won't work.  It is counting the line breaks (`\n`).

Anyone know of a way round this?

Many Thanks.

Comment: "the formatting items seem to be counted in the character limit". That seems to be the correct behaviour. If you try to post this on Twitter, it won't work since Twitter counts line breaks as characters.

Comment: No, it interprets them correctly as line breaks.  So if I shorten the message so that it is less than 280 char' in total, but still with some \n in it, then twitter does not show them as text "\n" - it correctly does line breaks in the tweet.  It it is difficult to show a working example due to the need to have secret token etc to post, but I can assure you it works - e.g. look at the recent tweets at @covidtracker7 and you will see some tweets that have line breaks in the text (but not "\n" anywhere, even though these were in the message that was used in the "post_tweet" command from R).

Comment: Yes, `\n` is interpreted as line break when posting. But Twitter is counting these towards the 280 limit anyway. You can test this by writing a tweet with 280 characters on the twitter website or app and then adding a line break/newline via hitting enter. You won't be able to post that tweet.

Comment: OK.  I was hoping to be able to add some other formatting when using post_tweet in the rtweet package. For example, I wanted to replace "up" with the html code for a red up arrow, but this would certainly have taken me over the 280 limit.  Do you or anyone else know of any better way to post formatted tweets from R   - or from something else that R can call ?(e.g. plenty of people post tweets with emojis, but they do that directly from their phone keyboards  - I want to do it from a program so that the tweet is produced when the program triggers it).  Perhaps I need to use media in the post.